# How to implement automatic achievements rule

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I ran across a challenge today. What I want to do is an automatic achievement system for my website. I want to check daily if users meet the requirements to get new achievements. Those requirements would not be stocked in the database, to add new achievements, I want to be able to only define a new javascript object/prototype, something along those lines.

I am working with sails and I don't know if my approach is right. I am making a service with a method "checkForAchievements" and I want it to check for all users and if they meet the requirements for every achievement defined. If they do, I would add a record in my table user_achievement. Here is what I tried so far :

```
exports.checkForAchievements = function(callback) {

  var AchievementsValidator = function(achievement, user) {
    this.achievement = achievement;
    this.user = user;
    this.validation = function() {
      return true;
    };
    this.giveAchievement = function() {
      UserAchievement.findOrCreate({ user: this.user, achievement: this.achievement}, { user:  this.user, achievement: this.achievement })
      .exec(function(err, userAchievment) {});
  }
  };

  //Example badge code, validation returns true if the user has at least 50 posts on the website
  var FiftyPosts = function() {
    this.validation = function() {
      Post.count({ user: this.user }).exec(function(err, count) {
        if (count >= 50) {
          return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      })
    };
  };

  //Loop in users and execute this code for each 
  FiftyPosts.prototype = new AchievementsValidator(22, user); // 22 would be the achivement in database
  if (FiftyPosts.validation) {
    FiftyPosts.giveAchievement();
  }
  callback();

};
```

Is it possible to get somewhere with this code? I feel like it would messy because I would need to write down each achivement in my final loop. Also, the code above is not working properly I can't get the validation to execute on the badge.

Note: Performance is not an issue as this code will not run often. I only want this to be scalable, so that I can add new achievements without too much hassle.
Thank you.

**EDIT:** It seems like the questions weren't clear enough so here you go :

1. How can I get FiftyPosts.validation to use the right method in the above code? It is not using any of the above (AchievementsValidator, FiftyPosts).
2. If you know sails.js enough can you tell me if doing this in a service is a good idea?

Comment: This might belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I don't want people to review my code, I want people to help me find a solution that fits the framework and my needs. Thank you.

Comment: Yea, but you're basically just asking people how you can make your code better. This isn't about a specific problem you're having.

Comment: @TravisWebb it doesn't sound like the code is working correctly: _"Also, the code above is not working properly I can't get the validation to execute on the badge"_. This would be off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: This question would be off-topic for [codereview.se].    Please don't recommend it be migrated there; the user doesn't want to ask his question there--he's not asking for a code review.  If you feel the question needs improvement in order to be a good [so] question, I suggest you either make edits or leave comments explaining how the asker can improve his question for [so].